# Jquery selecting hierarchies

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, hierarchy

Before I begin this question, if you're new to backbone.js and want to implement the following functionality you have to use the backbone relational model, or at least that's what it seems like.

I'm trying to create a hierarchy that will be implemented through backbone.js and I was wondering how to structure the hierarchy and access the elements. I need to be able to add and remove Lists/Sets/Items and hopefully keep a consistent numbering policy. (List1 would have a displayed name of list1. If I deleted Set1 I would want Set2 to become Set1 while retaining its corresponding items)

```
List1 
^--->Set1  
     ^--->Item1
     ^--->Item2
^--->Set2   
     ^--->Item1

List2 
^--->Set1  
     ^--->Item1
^--->Set2   
     ^--->Item1
     ^--->Item2
```

etc.

My question is this: How do you structure this in a way such that a set of functions following the same hierarchy can access them in the most compact and logical manner?

One idea I had:use div and just have your div id be something like id="List"+currentlistnum()+"Set"+currentsetnum()+"Item"+currentitemnum()

Is there a better way to do it than this?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, do you want to add event listenner to all `Item` items of every `List` items ?

Comment: And ironically your question is not clear to me either. Each Item should be a model with a view. Each set will have a collection of items associated with it and a RenderAllItems view. Same logic for Lists and sets.

Answer (score 3):

If you have list of items that is semantically a "list", use ordered list(ol) or unordered list(ul). Then if you have sub lists nest more lists.

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li>
        <span>List 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
            <span>Set1</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>List1Set1Item1</li>
                    <li>Item2</li>
                    <li>Item3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
            <span>Set2</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Item1</li>
                    <li>Item2</li>
                    <li>Item3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And use [jQuery nth Child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) and immediate child `>` for rest of logic to select particlar elements, so you can keep application logic away from HTML.

```
$('#mylist > li:nth-child(1) > span').text(); // List1
$('#mylist > li:nth-child(1) > ul > li:nth-child(1) > ul > li:nth-child(1)')
   .text(); //List1Set1Item1
```

If you want a numbering system attached: Example refresing all Set to update its number according to present view:

```
$('#mylist > li > ul > li > span').each(function(){
  var ordinalPositionOfMyParent = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
  $(this).text('Set' + ordinalPositionOfMyParent);
  });
```

Comment: Very good! I will try this solution out immediately and report back the results.

Comment: @Mark I have added an update pseudocode for refresing numbers, not optimal for huge lists.

Comment: Will this work for code like this? 'click button#addSetButton': 'addSet' I assume I just replace the #addSetButton with #mylist>li:nth-child(1)> ul > etc, this is for a backbone.js event

Comment: Each parent/child relationship will only have about 20 relations anyway